# Как реализовать Drag-and-drop в QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли (если можно, с помощью чего и как), реализовать Drag-and-drop текста в QPlainTextEdit.

Answer (score 2):

Класс QPlainTextEdit поддерживает перетягивание текста из коробки. Просто по-умолчанию это поддержка отключена, чтобы ее включить нужно выставить соответвующие свойства:

```
QPlaintTextEdit * edit = ... // откуда-нибудь берется готовый объект

edit->setDragEnabled (true);                 // включаем драг из edit
edit->setAcceptsDrops(true);                 // включаем дроп в edit
edit->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::CopyAction);  // по-умолчанию копируем

// можно настроить перетягивание за один раз
edit->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
```

Подробнее про перетягивание можно почитать в [справке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/dnd.html).